# SQL: How to select two employeeid within same team and have a team_score greater than 400 ? Mentioned the table schema below

Tags: sql, sqlite

Previous_teams

- id (integer)
- name (text)
- team_score (real)

Team_members

- team_id (integer)
- employee_id (integer)
- employee_name (text)
- birthday (text)
- popularity (real)

Q: How do I select a pair of employee ids that have worked in at least 5 prior teams where the (average)team_score was greater than 400 and count of teams where they worked together. Also avoid any duplicates. Example: team_id pairs of (1,2) need to be taken and not (2,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a self-join with some aggregation to count the teams that meet the conditions:

```
select tm1.employee_id, tm2.employee_id
from team_members tm1 inner join
     team_members tm2
     on tm1.team_id = tm2.team_id and
        tm1.employee_id < tm2.employee_id join
     previous_teams pt
     on tm1.team_id = pt.team_id
where pt.team_score > 400
group by tm1.employee_id, tm2.employee_id
having count(*) >= 5;
```

Comment: thanks a lot it does work! just curious how do I get the count of teams they have worked on together

Comment: @Dharight . . . If you want a count with the team score limit, then just add `count(*)` to the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select tm.employee_id
from team_members tm inner join previous_teams pt
on pt.id = tm.team_id
where pt.team_score > 400
group by tm.employee_id
having count(distinct tm.team_id) >= 5
```

you get all the `employee_id`s *that have worked in at least 5 prior teams where the team_score was greater than 400*.

You can get all the possible pairs of these `employee_id`s with a self join:

```
with cte as (
  select tm.employee_id
  from team_members tm inner join previous_teams pt
  on pt.id = tm.team_id
  where pt.team_score > 400
  group by tm.employee_id
  having count(distinct tm.team_id) >= 5
)
select c1.employee_id id1, c2.employee_id id2
from cte c1 inner join c2
on c2.employee_id > c1.employee_id
```

You may replace `having count(distinct tm.team_id) >= 5` with just `having count(*) >= 5` if there is no case of duplicate `team_id`s for each `employee_id`.